# Python unit test expectedFailureIf

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

I may be blind and missing something in the Python Unit Test FrameWork (Python 2.7.10).  I'm trying to mark a class as an expected failure but only if the class is run on Windows.  Other platforms work correctly.  So the basic concept would be:

```
@unittest.expectedFailureIf(sys.platform.startswith("win"), "Windows Fails")
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    # some class here
```

Comment: which version of python ?

Comment: Python Version 2.7.10

Comment: Python 2.7 doesn't have `@unittest.expectedFailureIf()`. Maybe you can use `@unittest.skipIf(sys.platform.startswith("win"), "Windows Fails")`

Comment: This request describes a concept.  Both platforms need to run.  If I mark them as expected failures they will return unexpected success on the Mac Platform.  Which of course is wrong.  They should report success or failure on the Macintosh while on Windows (because of a bug) they would report failures but with the concept of expectedFailureIf() they would be silenced on Windows and report as expectedFailures.  They will report unexpected fix the day that they are fixed.  A much better method since one platform will continue reporting valid results.  Skipping is not acceptable. Is there a way?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, neither Python 2 nor Python 3 (as at 3.8) have this built in.

You can pretty easily create this yourself, however, by defining it at the top of your file:

```
def expectedFailureIf(condition):
    """The test is marked as an expectedFailure if the condition is satisfied."""
    def wrapper(func):
        if condition:
            return unittest.expectedFailure(func)
        else:
            return func
    return wrapper
```

Then you can do essentially as you suggest (I have not added reason, as that isn't in the existing expectedFailure):

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    # some class here

    @expectedFailureIf(sys.platform.startswith("win"))
    def test_known_to_fail_on_windows_only(self):
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation **https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures

There is no `expectedFailureIf()`, you can use `expectedFailure()` or `skipIf(sys.platform.startswith("win", "Windows Fails"))`

Comment: Of course... I'm looking for a work around that doesn't involve skipIf() since I still want the Macintosh side to return valid test results.